How come the checkmark is still red, even tho its color is set to green
I have made this website that checks the strength of a given password
It looks like this

But the checkmarks stays red even though I have tried making it green.
What I want is the checkmark to be green and the X still to be red


document.getElementById("password").addEventListener("input", function() {
  var password = this.value.trim(); // Trim to remove leading and trailing spaces
  var capitalCheck = document.getElementById("capitalCheck").querySelector(".indicator");
  var numberCheck = document.getElementById("numberCheck").querySelector(".indicator");
  var symbolCheck = document.getElementById("symbolCheck").querySelector(".indicator");

  capitalCheck.textContent = /[A-Z]/.test(password) ? '✔' : '✘';
  numberCheck.textContent = /\d/.test(password) ? '✔' : '✘';
  symbolCheck.textContent = /[!@#$%^&*()_+\-=[\]{};':"\\|,.<>/?]/.test(password) ? '✔' : '✘';

  capitalCheck.style.visibility = /[A-Z]/.test(password) ? "visible" : "visible";
  numberCheck.style.visibility = /\d/.test(password) ? "visible" : "visible";
  symbolCheck.style.visibility = /[!@#$%^&*()_+\-=[\]{};':"\\|,.<>/?]/.test(password) ? "visible" : "visible";
});


function calculateTime() {
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
  var charCount = password.length;
  var hasUpperCase = /[A-Z]/.test(password);
  var hasNumber = /\d/.test(password);
  var hasSymbol = /[!@#$%^&*()_+\-=[\]{};':"\\|,.<>/?]/.test(password);

  var possibleCharacters = 26 + (hasUpperCase ? 26 : 0) + (hasNumber ? 10 : 0) + (hasSymbol ? 32 : 0); // lowercase letters + uppercase letters + numbers + symbols
  var permutations = Math.pow(possibleCharacters, charCount);

  var seconds = permutations / 1000000000; // divide by 1 billion to convert to seconds
  var minutes = seconds / 60;
  var hours = minutes / 60;
  var days = hours / 24;
  var years = days / 365;

  var result = "It would take approximately ";
  if (years >= 1) {
    result += Math.floor(years) + " years, " + Math.floor(days % 365) + " days, " + Math.floor(hours % 24) + " hours, " + Math.floor(minutes % 60) + " minutes, and " + Math.floor(seconds % 60) + " seconds to crack this password.";
  } else if (days >= 1) {
    result += Math.floor(days) + " days, " + Math.floor(hours % 24) + " hours, " + Math.floor(minutes % 60) + " minutes, and " + Math.floor(seconds % 60) + " seconds to crack this password.";
  } else if (hours >= 1) {
    result += Math.floor(hours) + " hours, " + Math.floor(minutes % 60) + " minutes, and " + Math.floor(seconds % 60) + " seconds to crack this password.";
  } else if (minutes >= 1) {
    result += Math.floor(minutes) + " minutes, and " + Math.floor(seconds % 60) + " seconds to crack this password.";
  } else {
    result += Math.ceil(seconds) + " seconds to crack this password.";
  }

  document.getElementById("result").innerText = result;
}
.info-container {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 400px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.criteria-item {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.container>h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

label {
  font-size: 16px;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

input[type="password"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #007bff;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #0056b3;
}

p#result {
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
}

ul.criteria {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

ul.criteria>li {
  font-size: 16px;
}

span.indicator {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: red;
}

span.valid {
  color: green;
}
<br> <br> <br>

<div class="info-container">
  <p>Indsæt tekst her...</p>
</div>


<div class="container">
  <h1>Password Strength Checker</h1>
  <label for="password">Enter Password:</label>
  <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
  <div class="criteria">
    <div class="criteria-item" id="capitalCheck">Capital Letters: <span class="indicator"></span></div>
    <div class="criteria-item" id="numberCheck">Numbers: <span class="indicator"></span></div>
    <div class="criteria-item" id="symbolCheck">Symbols: <span class="indicator"></span></div>
  </div>
  <button onclick="calculateTime()">Calculate</button>
  <div id="result"></div>
</div>




What steps have you taken to debug this? As far as I can tell, the checkmark has class="indicator" which should be red. The only item set to be green is a span with the valid class, which does not appear anywhere in your code.

I think you forgot to add valid to the span so it is not hit by span.valid which you set for color green. Also I update some of the code so you don't have to repeat the regular expression just for the same checking.


document.getElementById("password").addEventListener("input", function() {
  var password = this.value.trim(); // Trim to remove leading and trailing spaces
  var capitalCheck = document.getElementById("capitalCheck").querySelector(".indicator");
  var numberCheck = document.getElementById("numberCheck").querySelector(".indicator");
  var symbolCheck = document.getElementById("symbolCheck").querySelector(".indicator");

  checkPassword(password, capitalCheck, /[A-Z]/);
  checkPassword(password, numberCheck, /\d/);
  checkPassword(password, symbolCheck, /[!@#$%^&*()_+\-=[\]{};':"\\|,.<>/?]/);

});

function checkPassword(password, el, regex) {
  if (regex.test(password)) {
    el.textContent = '✔';
    el.classList.add('valid');

  } else {
    el.textContent = '✘';
    el.classList.remove('valid');
  }
  // not sure what is this doing, but I respect your code to keep it here
  el.style.visibility = 'visible';
}


function calculateTime() {
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
  var charCount = password.length;
  var hasUpperCase = /[A-Z]/.test(password);
  var hasNumber = /\d/.test(password);
  var hasSymbol = /[!@#$%^&*()_+\-=[\]{};':"\\|,.<>/?]/.test(password);

  var possibleCharacters = 26 + (hasUpperCase ? 26 : 0) + (hasNumber ? 10 : 0) + (hasSymbol ? 32 : 0); // lowercase letters + uppercase letters + numbers + symbols
  var permutations = Math.pow(possibleCharacters, charCount);

  var seconds = permutations / 1000000000; // divide by 1 billion to convert to seconds
  var minutes = seconds / 60;
  var hours = minutes / 60;
  var days = hours / 24;
  var years = days / 365;

  var result = "It would take approximately ";
  if (years >= 1) {
    result += Math.floor(years) + " years, " + Math.floor(days % 365) + " days, " + Math.floor(hours % 24) + " hours, " + Math.floor(minutes % 60) + " minutes, and " + Math.floor(seconds % 60) + " seconds to crack this password.";
  } else if (days >= 1) {
    result += Math.floor(days) + " days, " + Math.floor(hours % 24) + " hours, " + Math.floor(minutes % 60) + " minutes, and " + Math.floor(seconds % 60) + " seconds to crack this password.";
  } else if (hours >= 1) {
    result += Math.floor(hours) + " hours, " + Math.floor(minutes % 60) + " minutes, and " + Math.floor(seconds % 60) + " seconds to crack this password.";
  } else if (minutes >= 1) {
    result += Math.floor(minutes) + " minutes, and " + Math.floor(seconds % 60) + " seconds to crack this password.";
  } else {
    result += Math.ceil(seconds) + " seconds to crack this password.";
  }

  document.getElementById("result").innerText = result;
}
.info-container {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 400px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.criteria-item {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.container>h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

label {
  font-size: 16px;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

input[type="password"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #007bff;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #0056b3;
}

p#result {
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
}

ul.criteria {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

ul.criteria>li {
  font-size: 16px;
}

span.indicator {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: red;
}

span.valid {
  color: green;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Password Strength Checker</title>
</head>

<body>
  <br> <br> <br>

  <div class="info-container">
    <p>Indsæt tekst her...</p>
  </div>


  <div class="container">
    <h1>Password Strength Checker</h1>
    <label for="password">Enter Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
    <div class="criteria">
      <div class="criteria-item" id="capitalCheck">Capital Letters: <span class="indicator"></span></div>
      <div class="criteria-item" id="numberCheck">Numbers: <span class="indicator"></span></div>
      <div class="criteria-item" id="symbolCheck">Symbols: <span class="indicator"></span></div>
    </div>
    <button onclick="calculateTime()">Calculate</button>
    <div id="result"></div>
  </div>



